# Can't render react component: ReactJS unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs, unexpected-token

I am trying to render a react component dynamically but I am getting an unexpected token error and am not sure why.

Error:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 9:3:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   7 | 
   8 | 
>  9 |   <ContactCards
     |   ^
  10 |   contact={{name: "Mr whiskerson", imgurl: "http://placekitten.com/300/300", phone:"04019292", email: "whiskahs@gmail.com"}}
  11 |   />
  12 |
```

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ContactCards from './ContactCards'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="contacts"


  <ContactCards
  contact={{name: "Mr whiskerson", imgurl: "http://placekitten.com/300/300", phone:"04019292", email: "whiskahs@gmail.com"}}
  />


  <ContactCards
  contact={{name: "Mr Jack Sparrow", imgurl: "http://placekitten.com/300/300", phone:"(252) 9483282)", email: "Jack@sparrow.com"}}
  />

  <ContactCards
  contact={{name: "Mr Jiu Hello Cat", imgurl: "http://placekitten.com/300/300", phone:"(852) 0411928483", email: "JiuCat@school.com "}}
  />
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't close off the div at

```
<div className="contacts"
```

End the tag with a closing token.

```
<div className="contacts">
```

Answer (score 0):

Single Curly braces are used to paas props to a component. You are using double curly braces instead use single

```
<ContactCards
 contact={name: "Mr whiskerson", imgurl: "http://placekitten.com/300/300", 
 phone:"04019292", email: "whiskahs@gmail.com"}
/>
```